# For loop in a timer- C#

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, for-loop, timer

I have a `Datagridview` that contains few columns and data in each row. I need to regularly send complete Datagridview data, each row data one at a time, sequentially to a `web browser` in my application, which will actually append this row data to a URL of a website that will echo whatever data is appended to it. So for this purpose I used a `timer` which will send all the data once for every `10 seconds`. Inside the timer to send each row one at a time I used the following `for loop`:

```
private void tmr_senddata_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(dg_parameters.Rows.Count!=1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dg_parameters.Rows.Count-1; i++)
        {
            string row = "";
            string cell = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < dg_parameters.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                cell = cell + dg_parameters.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value;
                cell = cell + "@";
                row = cell;
            }
            string uri = webBrowser1.Url + row;
            webBrowser1.Navigate(uri);
        }
    }
}
```

Now what I end up is only the `last row being displayed on the browser`. This is because by the time my browser navigates to the URL specified for the first time in my loop, next iteration takes and URL changes. So only my last row data is navigated properly and displayed on browser. How do I stop the for loop for a specified time every time so that I can see my browser navigate to the URL. I believe `Thread.Sleep()` is not a good idea because it blocks my UI thread.

**UPDATE:** This is a simulation application used to test a particular scenario. So please ignore the reason in doing this. A solution to the problem will do good.

Comment: I don't get it how you can "navigate to a row". Are you actually trying to put HTML _content_ inside the `Url` property of the web browser?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? What's your business requirement?

Comment: The web page is designed in that way, so that it echo's whatever data is appended to the url back on the screen. So I just append the row data to the url and navigate it

Comment: @Enigmativity Did a small update to the question. Right now I just need to see that the all the gridview data is echoed properly

Comment: do your task in a new thread and sleep that thread instead of application main thread so it pauses your for loop for an amount of time and your application keeps running since you have not made the main thread sleep.

Comment: Well, you could do it in a background thread then (`BackgroundWorker`) through `Invoke` method of the gridview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your `dg_parameters.Rows` in a [`Queue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx) when your application starts.

Each time the timer fires, call `myQueue.Dequeue` to get the next item to use.

Comment: +1. Much easier than manually doing on iteration in callback or manually using IEnumrable (obtained with Enumerable.Range)

Comment: I dint get it. How do I achieve the time gap here between each navigation?

Comment: The time gap is achieved by the timer, each time the timer triggers you navigate once, to the next one in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Why not you use [`WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted Event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted). 
Once the document is fully downloaded you can call your tmr_senddata_Tick.
You can also transfer whole thing on a background thread if you dont want your interface to suffer.

Example:-

```
private void setevent()
{
    webBrowserForPrinting.DocumentCompleted +=
        new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(NavigateTo);

}

private void NavigateTo(object sender,
    WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   //Pause thread as per the need.
   if(dg_parameters.Rows.Count!=1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dg_parameters.Rows.Count-1; i++)
            {
                string row = "";
                string cell = "";
                for (int j = 0; j < dg_parameters.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    cell = cell + dg_parameters.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value;
                    cell = cell + "@";
                    row = cell;
                }
                string uri = webBrowser1.Url + row;
                webBrowser1.Navigate(uri);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: While it is good suggestion to use event to check if navigation is  completed I don't see how it solves "one item per navigation" which is what original question is about.

Comment: Sorry cant get you, but AFAI understood he perhaps want to navigate to some url ,on at a time.and this template can help OP establishing the whole need.

Comment: Maybe - let's OP vote on it. My understanding of the question is: how to split `for` loop between separate callbacks (timer/navigate...).

Comment: :).. OP is the verdict, Sometime its really difficult writing *he or she* ;)